# How to update a serial number in oracle table based on time of entry of the record in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named entryform having the following columns
`NAME,BOOKING_TIME,SN`
The NAME and BOOKING_TIME fields are entered by the users. The SN field is to be updated based on the ascending sequence of BOOKING_TIME.

Can some please help me out to write the SQL query for performing the above operation in ORACLE

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `row_number()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by booking_time) as sn
from t;
```

The difference is that `dense_rank()` can remove duplicates if `booking_time` has duplicate values.

If you actually want to update the value, you can use `merge`, assuming you have a primary key of some type:

```
merge into t using
      (select t.*,
              row_number() over (order by booking_time) as new_sn
       from t
      ) tt
      on (t.pk = tt.pk)
when matched then
    update set t.sn = tt.new_sn;
```